# Erro back-up wordpress pasta wp-content hospedado na hostgator

Tags: wordpress, backup

Preciso migrar um site `WordPress` (WooCommerce) da Hostgator para a Digital Ocean. Contudo, não consigo ter acesso a pasta *wp-content*. Já fiz backup do site todo via Hostgator, mas ela vem vazia. Instalei um *plugin* para *backup* no Dropbox, mas quando chega na pasta *wp-content*, um erro ocorre e o *backup* não acontece. A pasta tem permissão permissão 755.

> Citação
>   11:43:52: A fatal error occured: The backup is having trouble uploading files to Dropbox, it has failed 10 times and is aborting the backup.
>   Citação
>   11:43:52: Processed 11 files.
>   11:43:52: Error uploading '/home/banil436/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/404.php' to Dropbox: Expecting a file upload

Alguma dica para fazer essa migração sem perder nenhuma informação (pedidos,clientes,etc)?

Comment: Sabe o tamanho da pasta? Chegou a fuçar via ftp pra ver se não tem nada estranho dentro?

Comment: @brasofilo ta normal site funcionando, bom essa parte junto a hostgator eu to acompanhando de longe outra pessoa esta vendo, mas o que me passou é que a principio nao tinha permissao para mexer nessa pasta via ftp, ai flw no suporte e eles mexeram, mandaram fazer o backup do site inteiro, porem quando fui ate a pasta falava que eu nao tinha permissao, entao via terminal dei permissao 777 mas abri ela e estava vazia ...   A pasta tem uns 100 megas.

Comment: Parece que o problema é mais grave que um simples plugin de backup, não?

Comment: Bom vou detalhar o que preciso.

Uma amiga tem um site na hostgator é uma loja e esta funcionando certinho, porem vamos migrar para digitalocean onde ja preparei o servidor esta tudo ok, la na digitalocean eu configurei tudo com outro dominio que estava parado, para nao tirar a loja atual do ar, ai quero migrar todo conteudo da atual para a nova ai testo e se tiver tudo ok migro o dominio tb, mas ai que esta o problema nao estou conseguindo faz o backup do conteudo para levar para o novo servidor ... Em especial a pasta wp-content sempre que chega nela da problema.@brasofilo

Comment: Tentou zipar tudo via WebFTP no Hostgator? (isso seria pra um transfer manual, mas bom parece que 1o problema é tirar as coisas de lá)

Comment: @brasofilo  foi feito um backup geral na hostgator, veio zipado abri o arquivo cacei a pasta wp-content a principio tentei abrir flw que eu não tinha permissao, então achei ela via temrinal e dei permissao, porem quando abri estava vazia ... Usando plugin tb nao resolvou da erro no backup quando chega na pasta wp-content

Comment: Ou seja, o zip tá corrompendo na origem? No Hostgator? Confere no admin do WP se não tem nada estranho na biblioteca de mídia, talvez algum upload zicou tudo... (?)

Comment: Ao que parece sim ta corrompendo, mas justo essa pasta rs ... Esta na hostgator .... Na parte de midia no WP a unica coisa difirerente de imagens são arquivos CSV com os produtos da loja. @brasofilo